# Get to know a particular Ubuntu system via IP address

Tags: networking, ip, ubuntu-14.04

We have around 70 computers running Ubuntu in our lab which are connected to the same internet network via the ethernet cables. When I scan all hosts which are up using nmap with the following command `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` I get the list of active hosts. With a particular IP address, say for example - `192.169.0.119` . How can I tell this is the IP address of a particular system? I mean how can I identify a computer among 70 of them with a known IP address.

Comment: I'm sorry it failed to identify the particular system among 70 of them. Anyways, thanks for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
nmblookup -A <ip>
```

If you can install nbtscan try

```
nbtscan <ip>
```

Latter may only give resolution for Win machines on the network.